# Archiving annual festival site

Tags: themes, archives, design, management

I have a query regarding managing a wordpress setup, I am sure others have been in a similar situation and was wondering what would be the best solution.

I manage an annual festival's website, each year has a different theme / design and event details, this is archived each year [ ie at festival.com/2008/ etc.]

Last year we moved to a wordpress platform and all was good, now have a new theme for this years festival and the new event details ready to go but I have a dillema...

Is it possible to have one wp blog with an archive of last years festival ie 2010 theme and 2010 events/pages accessed via festival.com/2010/ and this year events/pages and theme show up when visiting the main site [ ie festival.com/ ]

so i need one blog with multiple themes and event filtering

I can filter event/page by a year category but will this mess the menus etc.
or am i best off just moving the existing wp install to the festival.com/2010/ directory and creating a new blog and in the site root [ festival.com] ?

any suggestions, advice or pointers would be great,

Thanks in advance,

Keith

Comment: Just for reference I started with static-html-output-plugin but ran into issues, in the end I went with wget - this allowed me to exclude directories eg post and previous years archives    `wget -q --mirror -p --html-extension --base=./ --exclude-directories=2008/,2009/,2010/,2011/,news/  -k -P ./ http://domain.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally.

I would archive the 2010/etc sites to Pure HTML.

This plugin would do the job http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/static-html-output-plugin/

This WordPress codex post describes another method. With using WordPress in its own Sub Directory and archiving sites: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Pointing_your_home_site.27s_URL_to_a_subdirectory

Comment: Thanks that worked a treat .don't have enough rep points on wp.stackexchange to upvote :(